# CSS Outer shadow + Inner shadow create an unwanted black outline

Tags: css

Based on the codes below, anyone know how I can remove the tiny black outline? I just want to see the circle glow.

```css
body {
  background:#1f1f1f;
  width:100px;
  margin:60px auto;
}

.inner {
  background-color:transparent;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 50px rgba(255, 242, 87, 0.5), inset 0 0 30px 30px rgba(255, 242, 87, 0.5);
}
```

```html
 <div class="inner"></div>
```

Comment: I think it would be easiest to use a radial gradient on the background.

Comment: @mrmonsieur not sure what you mean by that. My end product should be a yellow glow in a circle shape.

Comment: FYI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient()

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  background:#1f1f1f;
  width:100px;
  margin:60px auto;
}

.inner {
  background-color:transparent;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#1f1f1f 30%, rgba(255, 242, 87, 0.5) 55%, #1f1f1f 70.71%);
}
```

```html
 <div class="inner"></div>
```

I am not much of a gradient expert myself, you can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients to see how u can use gradients in all kinds of ways. But I think this does what you need.

Comment: Anyway to remove the center border circle? Just want the blur yellow part.. I feel like with radial-gradient can't achieve the same effect from the one I made..

Comment: The specs say the following: "A non-zero blur radius indicates that the resulting shadow should be blurred, such as by a Gaussian filter. The exact algorithm is not defined; however the resulting shadow must approximate (with each pixel being within 5% of its expected value) the image that would be generated by applying to the shadow a Gaussian blur with a standard deviation equal to half the blur radius." You could use this to calculate a bunch of values and closely approximate the shadow with a gradient if you were really persistent.

Comment: Otherwise you could make an element whose border overlaps with the circle and give it a tiny border.

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  background:#1f1f1f;
  width:100px;
  margin:60px auto;
}

.inner {
  background-color:transparent;
  width:350px;
  height:400px;
  border-radius:100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center,
                      transparent 20%,
                      rgba(255, 242, 87, 0.15)  24%,
                      rgba(255, 242, 87, 0.29)  28%,
                      rgba(255, 242, 87, 0.40)  32%,
                      rgba(255, 242, 87, 0.475) 36%,
                      rgba(255, 242, 87, 0.5)  40%,
                      rgba(255, 242, 87, 0.475) 45%,
                      rgba(255, 242, 87, 0.40)  50%,
                      rgba(255, 242, 87, 0.29)  55%,
                      rgba(255, 242, 87, 0.15)  60%,
                      transparent 65%);
}
```

```html
 <div class="inner"></div>
```

Comment: The effect is so far away from mine. I don't think it's possible with radial-gradient.

Comment: @iceiceicy I had the color intensity wrong, it looks closer now.  You can definitely get a closer effect by adding more stops.  The two things I'm not sure how to fixe are 1) your ring is much bigger, this is because drop-shadows fall outside of their object (I guess I could make the size bigger), and 2) I'm not sure why the outer edge is not fading to transparency correctly.  I'll play around with it to see if I can improve it.

Comment: @iceiceicy OK, does that look better?

Comment: yup.. Thank you! I'll play around with it to see can make the glow more softer or not..

Comment: @iceiceicy It's tricky as heck.  If I push the outer boundary any further than about 65% then the border-radius starts to cut if off with a sharp circular edge.  If the stops are too far apart, then you start to get those bright ridges I had earlier.  I had to lower the maximum opaqueness to keep it from being too bright/solid. And I had to use SIN() function to set opaqueness(A) values to make the shading look right and smooth enough.